# Rendering MathJax after loading content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mathjax

I load some content containing math with jQuery into my html file. Now I want Mathjax to typeset this new content, but it doesn't work. This is what my JavaScript code looks like

```html
<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js"></script>


<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#newContent").click(function(){
          $("#content").load("{% static 'newContent.txt' %}");
          MathJax.typeset();
        });
      });
</script>
```

But it only loads the content without applying MathJax. Any suggestions why it is not working?

---

**Edit** I added a second button with a second click function, which runs the following script

```html
<script>
  function myfunction(){
    MathJax.typeset();
  }
</script>
```

If I click the first button, then it loads the new content without applying MathJax. If I now click the second button, it applies MathJax to the new content. This tells me that it is possible to apply MathJax to my loaded content, however, loading new content and typesetting it with one click doesn't work so far.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `async` attribute from the script tag loading MathJax?

Comment: @NathanielVerhaaren The problem still persists. I added an edit, maybe it helps understanding why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `load` sends an [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) request, which is asynchronous. This means it is possible (and very likely) that the code after the call to `load` gets executed before the server has sent a response. In the above example, the call to `load` starts an asynchronous request, then the call to `MathJax.typeset()` runs while there is still no math on the page, so nothing happens. Finally, the `load` request completes, loading the math content.

In order to ensure the typesetting happens after the math is loaded, the call to `MathJax.typeset` must occur in a callback function provided to the `load` call. Based on the example [in the jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load/), this would look like

```js
$("#content").load("{% static 'newContent.txt' %}", () => MathJax.typeset());
```

You can let MathJax know which element to render by providing its id in an array:

```js
$("#content").load("{% static 'newContent.txt' %}", () => MathJax.typeset(['content']));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do you do it in JavaScript?